# Projection of a sphere's surface vs that of the inner side of the surface

Tags: spherical-trigonometry, stereographic-projections

I want to project a catalog of stars on a sphere to the computer screen. As a non-mathematician I was looking for a ready made solution and I found some interesting geographical projections, like Mercator.

Here's the riddle I'm struggling with:

Is the outcome of a projection from a sphere's surface to a plane (2-dimensional geographical map) identical to the projection of the inner side of a sphere's surface to a plane (2-dimensional starchart)?

I'm pretty sure that this is true for points, but I'm not sure if it also works for lines and areas.

Any hint would be appreciated.

[image: 2 types of projection]

Comment: Please note that in mathematics surfaces are assumed to have "no thickness". So if my "sphere's inside" you mean the inner side of a sphere's *surface*, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for helping me with the correct terms. I edited my question accordingly.